# select from 3 different cases

Tags: sql, hiveql

I have some different records for each flight_no in some cases. It looks like the below.
I would like to select only one row for each flight_no by the order shown on the right - so if there is time in both of the fields, select 1, if not, select one with landing+null (2), if not select null (3).

Thanks for helping

[image]

Comment: check out case when

Answer (score 0):

Given the following..

```
create table flight (
    id int identity(1,1) not null,
    flight_no int not null,
    landing datetime null,
    departuring datetime null
)

insert flight (flight_no, landing, departuring)
values (9180, {ts '2021-06-16 20:18:00.000'}, null)
, (9180, null, null)
, (9180, {ts '2021-06-16 20:18:00.000'}, {ts '2021-06-16 21:39:00.000'})
```

(I did that in SQL Server.  Your mileage may vary.)

You should be able to do something like this:

```
select flight_no
, landing
, departuring

from (
    select flight_no
    , landing
    , departuring
    , [order]
    , min([order]) over (partition by flight_no) as minorder

    from (
        select flight_no
        , landing
        , departuring
        , case
            when landing is not null and departuring is not null
                then 1
            when landing is not null
                then 2
            else 3
          end as 'order'

        from flight
    ) a
) b

where [order] = minorder
```

And I have seen in other SO posts that common table expressions are possible in `hiveql`, so...

```
with a as (
    select flight_no
    , landing
    , departuring
    , case
        when landing is not null and departuring is not null
            then 1
        when landing is not null
            then 2
        else 3
        end as 'order'

    from flight
),
b as (
    select flight_no
    , landing
    , departuring
    , [order]
    , min([order]) over (partition by flight_no) as minorder

    from a
)

select flight_no
, landing
, departuring

from b

where [order] = minorder
```

Answer (score 0):

Use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by flight_no
                                order by (case when landing is not null then 1 else 0 end) + (case when departuring is not null then 1 else 0 end) desc
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

The `order by` expression is counting the number of non-`NULL` values in the two columns.